# Doctrine2 - Saving custom join relation table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, database-relations

Basically, I have two tables (Article and Tag) and I want to make many-to-many (one article can have many tags, one tag can be assigned to many articles) relation with some extra attributes.
I can write this in Doctrine2 by breaking it into two separate relations (one-to-many, many-to-one) and one relation table ArticleTag with my extra attributes.

My problem is that I don't know if I can make Doctrine2 to create also the join table entities for me. What I mean is when I call:

```
$article = /* create new article, etc... */
$tag = /* create new tag, etc... */
$article->addTag($tag);

$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

It **DOES** create both Article and Tag entities in the database but it **DOES NOT** create ArticleTag entity (in other words, it doesn't create the connection between Article and Tag). I could create it on my own but I would rather rely on Doctrine2.
Of course, it works fine when I use standard join table generated by Doctrine2 but I need those extra attributes.

Does anyone have any idea or do I really have to do it manually?

EDIT: source codes

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ArticleTag", joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * )
     */
    protected $tags;

    ...
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArticleTag {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article")
     */
     private $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $tag;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    protected $priority = 0.5;

}
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $name;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way to do this automatically, per se, but you can change the `addTag` method on the `Article` class to something like this:

```
public function addTag(Tag $tag, $priority)
{
    $articleTag = new ArticleTag();
    $articleTag->setTag($tag);
    $articleTag->setArticle($this);
    $articleTag->setPriority($priority);
    $this->addArticleTag($articleTag);
    return $this;
}
```

That way, you keep your code centralized and hide the creation of the `ArticleTag` entry. For an additional explanation, here's the reasoning behind this logic:

A class in the eyes of Doctrine represents an entity source, and each instance of that class represents an entity. In a simple many-to-many table, the many-to-many table is not an entity. In fact, it is merely a relationship between two entities, which is why Doctrine allows you to bypass this logic and doesn't require an `ArticleTag` entity if it only has foreign keys.

However, once you add additional metadata to that table, it is no longer a relationship table. I have discussed this with many people who see things differently, but it's just not. Yes, it's defining that entity 1 and entity 2 are related, but that additional column defines additional metadata that is required with the association. Therefore it is an entity on its own and must be reflected as such.

I had struggled with this for quite some time until I ended up adding the code that I showed above.

Comment: I understand that ArticleTag isn't relation table because of my extra 'priority' column, but I'm surprised that Doctrine2 can't handle this entity the same way is it was autogenerated.

Comment: I was loking for an answer to the same problem. However, Colin's solution is not perfect, because it works only in unidirectional relations.

If you manage tags from articles, but don't manage articles from tags, it's ok. As soon as you want to be able to use also a "addArticle()" method in the Tag entity, you could have to deal with two identical ArticleTag entities. Indeed, "addTag()" and "addArticle()" would both create an ArticleTag with same values.

It's also only a partial solution because it lacks management of persistence and removal.

Comment: @Ninj My solution could be relatively easily modified to support removal as well as bi-directional relationships. That just wasn't asked for in this question.

Answer (score 0):

My Entities can join articles with their tags (subjects in my schema) without any joining entity, do you need the joining entity for any specific reason?

usage

```
$article->getSubjects()->add($subject);
```

entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\Fam\Article")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Article")
 */
class Article{

    /*StartProtected*/

        protected $links = array();

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->subjects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Subject")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Article_to_Subject",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleId", referencedColumnName="articleId")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="subjectId", referencedColumnName="subjectId")}
         *      )
         */
        protected $subjects;

        /**
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection 
         */
        public function getSubjects()
        {
            return $this->subjects;
        }        

        public function removeSubjects(){ $this->subjects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); return $this;  }
```

Comment: Well, I need assign some attributes to each relation, therefore I need the joining entity.

Comment: darn, my excitement about finding an unanswered question I thought I knew got the better of me ;)